# React native axios is not working properly

Tags: react-native

I have this route on me BE

```
app.get('/welcomeRoute',(req,res)=> {
    res.send("Hello world")
})


app.listen(4000,()=> {
    console.log("Server is up")
})
```

I installed axios on my react native project with `npm i axios` , I created my project with `expo init`.

Here is how I use route

```
test = () => {
 axios.get('http://localhost:4000/welcomeRoute').then((res)=> {
   console.log('--------res', res);
 }).catch((err)=> {
   console.log('--------err', err);
 })
```

}

Whenever i call this route i Always get `--------err [Error: Network Error]`.
I tested this route in the `postman` and it is working fine.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: try `https` instead of http may be its work.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is on Android, the solution is to add below in in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

In IOS, unencrypted network requests are blocked by default, i.e. https will work, http will not.

> Your server from your emulator/device you need to access server via IP Address. Instead of http://localhost:port you should use http://your_ip_address:port

Comment: I created my app with expo init so i dont have any androidManifest file :(

Comment: Instead of http://localhost:port you should use http://your_ip_address:port.Try with it

Answer (score 0):

Actually in React Native you better give ip address of system rather than localhost because the device don't recognize your ip address using localhost